# When sending an image to web server, what do we actually send?

Tags: image, post, file-upload, web-applications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THSFB.png)

What do we really send from frontend to backend?

Answer (score 0):

base64 is one way to do it.
We can encode the image into base64 and send it to the backend. then back-end should decode it and save a specific location in the server.